# Job Alert, checking saved searche per Job to return respective UserIDs

Tags: sql, sql-server, logic

I'm trying to work out how to calculate if a users search matches that of a newly posted job.

I plan to start with a JobID and work back to find all UserIDs that have a saved search.

```
Jobs

JobID   WorkingHoursID  JobTypeID   AlertChecked
4       1               1           0
5       3               4           0
```

---

```
UserJobSearches

UserID  JobSearchID Saved   Alert   SearchName
1       2043        1       1       User1
2       2044        1       1       User2
```

---

```
Job Searches

JobSearchID     SearchDate              Radius
2043            2016-10-27 12:42:19     NULL
2044            2016-10-27 12:43:19     NULL
```

---

```
JobSearchWorkingHours

JobSearchID WorkingHoursID
2043        1
2044        2
```

---

```
JobSearchJobTypes

JobSearchID JobTypeID
2043        1
2044        1
```

---

```
-- get UserIDs from UserJobSearches using JobsearchID from sub query
Select UserID FROM UserJobSearches WHERE JobSearchID IN(

    -- get jobsearch id from jobsearches
    SELECT JobSearchID FROM JobSearches WHERE JobSearchID IN(

        -- get the WorkingHoursID
        SELECT JobSearchID FROM JobSearchWorkingHours WHERE (
            WorkingHoursID IS NULL 
            OR 
            WorkingHoursID IN (
                SELECT WorkingHoursID FROM Jobs WHERE JobID = 4
            )
        )

    ) AND JobSearchID IN(

        -- get the JobTypeID
        SELECT JobSearchID FROM JobSearchJobTypes WHERE (
            JobTypeID IS NULL 
            OR 
            JobTypeID IN(
                SELECT JobTypeID FROM Jobs WHERE JobID = 4
            )
        ) 

    )

)
```

My issue is around excluding a search if it has a condition that doesn't match entirely. 
I also need to say if the search doesn't contain a field don't exclude the result

So I almost need to say get the WorkingHoursID and the JobSearchID WHERE it matches that of a search or isn't included?

I've made multiple attempts to write something for this. But keep finding myself stuck and confused. Any advice or help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Somethig similar would work. You need to join all your search criteria with a INNER JOIN and then optionally join the jobs on matching LEFT OUTER JOIN. Finally join the Jobs table again to get all the results. There are better ways to do this as the amount of search criteria increases, however, this should be fine for two search conditions.

```
SELECT
    UserID,
    JobSearchID,
    JobID,
    MatchesHours=CASE WHEN X.MatchesHoursJobID IS NULL  THEN 0 ELSE 1 END,
    MatchesJobType=CASE WHEN X.MatchesJobTypeJobID IS NULL  THEN 0 ELSE 1 END
FROM
(
    SELECT
        UserID,
        JobSearchID,
        MatchesHoursJobID=CASE WHEN HoursMatch.JobID IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END,
        MatchesJobTypeJobID=CASE WHEN JobTypeMatch.JobID IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END
    FROM 
        UserJobSearches UJS
        INNER JOIN JobSearches JS ON JS.JobSearchID=UJS.JobSearchID
        INNER JOIN JobSearchJobTypes JSJT ON JSJT.JobSearchID =UJS.JobSearchID 
        INNER JOIN JobSearchWorkingHours JSWH ON JSWH.JobSearchID =UJS.JobSearchID 
        LEFT OUTER JOIN Jobs HoursMatch ON Jobs.WorkingHoursID=JSWH.WorkingHoursID
        LEFT OUTER JOIN Jobs JobTypeMatch ON Jobs.JobTypeID =JSWH.JobTypeID   
)AS X
INNER JOIN Jobs ON  Jobs.JobID=MatchesHoursJobID OR Jobs.JobID=MatchesJobTypeJobID
```

Comment: This is great thanks Ross. Unfortunately there's over 100k of records and many many more search criteria :( Had just simplified for SO. Could you point me to reading/examples of how I could achieve this without joins?

Comment: If this is the case then I would build up a temp table of results. For each criteria add the jobs that match to the temp table and then craft your results.

Comment: Thanks Ross, have been told it would be more efficient to do it one JobID at a time. Once the jobs dealt with I wont touch it again. I guess the same principle could apply though? N.B. I've figured out how to check for null. Have updated my answer. Don't feel much would need to change to get it to work now, do you think its possible?

Comment: In that case, just add a @JobID parameter.